# Magento 2 get customer login or not in Js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer, login

We want to check if customer is login.

Only in that case we want to run particular script in Js file.

Answer (score -1):

We can do this by using :
`window.isCustomerLoggedIn & window.customerData`

This returns true or false depends upon customer session.